# Prevent multiple user login - HttpSessionBindingListener

Tags: java, servlets, authentication

I have a web application where I want to prevent a user login multiple times (from different browsers on the same machine or from different machines).

I read about HttpSessionBindingListener and I tried to adapt my login servlet and my user Bean to implement the desired solution. Unfortunately it only works when I login the second time on the same browser (in a different tab) but if I change browser (on the same machine) it doesn't work anymore.

The code is as follows.

**User Bean to put in session after successful login in**

```
public class BeanUtente implements HttpSessionBindingListener {

private String username;
private String gruppo;

public boolean ruoloPresente(String nomeRuolo) {
    //se il gruppo dell'utente è uguale a quello richiesto dal filtro
    if (this.gruppo.equals(nomeRuolo))
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}

public void valueBound(HttpSessionBindingEvent argo) {
    System.out.println("Value Bound Called, " + argo.getValue() + " isNewSession: " + argo.getSession().isNew());
}

public void valueUnbound(HttpSessionBindingEvent argo) {
    System.out.println("Value UnBound Called, " + argo.getValue() + " isNewSession: " + argo.getSession().isNew());
}

public String toString() {
    return "Username is: " + username;
}

public String getUsername() {
    return username;
}

public void setUsername(String username) {
    this.username = username;
}

public String getGruppo() {
    return gruppo;
}

public void setGruppo(String gruppo) {
    this.gruppo = gruppo;
}
```

}

**Login servlet**

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    Db db = null;
    PreparedStatement ps = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;

    try {
        response.setHeader("Cache-Control","no-cache,no-store,must-revalidate");
        response.setHeader("Pragma","no-cache");
        response.setDateHeader("Expires", 0);

        Locale locale = request.getLocale();
        ResourceBundle labels = ResourceBundle.getBundle("risorse.label", locale);

        String urlLoginOk = getInitParameter("urlLoginOk");
        String urlLoginKo = getInitParameter("urlLoginKo");

        String username = request.getParameter("username");
        String password = request.getParameter("password");

        db = new Db();
        db.apriConnessione();

        String sql = "SELECT gruppo FROM Utenti WHERE username=? AND password=SHA2(?, 512)";

        ps = db.getConnection().prepareStatement(sql);
        ps.setString(1, username);
        ps.setString(2, password);
        rs = ps.executeQuery();

        //login OK
        if(username != null && password != null && rs.next()) {
            BeanUtente beanUtente = new BeanUtente();
            beanUtente.setUsername(username);
            beanUtente.setGruppo(rs.getString("gruppo"));

            HttpSession sess = request.getSession();
            sess.setAttribute("beanUtente", beanUtente);

            request.getRequestDispatcher(urlLoginOk).forward(request, response);
        }
        //login KO
        else {
            request.setAttribute("errore", labels.getString("loginFallito"));
            request.getRequestDispatcher(urlLoginKo).forward(request, response);
        }

    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally {
        try {
            if(!ps.isClosed())
                ps.close();
            if(!rs.isClosed())
                rs.close();
        }
        catch (SQLException sqle) {
            sqle.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally {
            if(db.getConnection() != null)
                db.chiudiConnessione();
        }
    }

}
```

Here is the log.
When I login the first time, I get:

```
*Value Bound Called, Username is: pi isNewSession: false*
```

When I login the second time from the same browser, I get:

```
*Value Bound Called, Username is: pi isNewSession: false
Value UnBound Called, null isNewSession: false*
```

So it seems the UnBound method is correctly called.
However, if I login the third time from another browser on the same machine, I get:

```
*Value Bound Called, Username is: pi isNewSession: false*
```

that is, the UnBound method has not been called.

Can you help me to understand where is my mistake?
I suppose I have to explicity invoke session.removeAttribute("beanUtente") but when/where?

Thanks in advance for any help :)

Answer (score 0):

To avoid login from multiple browser,i don't think so that `HttpSessionBindingListener` will work,because with new browser,it will create new session.

You will have to save the state at your backend for the particular user,let say `userId` for each user,may be in `cache/DB`,once he login, and remove it from `cache/DB` once he log out,

So when user login do like below.
Object user =  getUser(userId);

if(user != null){
  // user already logged in,just return custom message
}
else{
  // Allow user to login
}

Similary on `logout` remove the `userId` from `cache/user`.

Comment: Hi, the problem is when the user closes the browser without logging out. I need a way to timeout the user bean in session/context.

Comment: unable to understand your problem??

Comment: suppose that after first login I put userID in context or in DB and that I have a logout servlet that, if called by user click, removes userID from context/DB. If user1 correctly logout, there is no problem. The problem occurs when user1 closes browser without logout; in this case, if user1 try to login again to the application, the login servlet will return an error message because userID of user1 already exists in context/DB. So, I need a way to remove userID from context/DB after a predetermined amount of time has been elapsed since a previous operation.

Answer (score 0):

```
    @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http
                    .authorizeRequests()
                    .mvcMatchers("/").permitAll()
                    .and().sessionManagement()
                    .maximumSessions(1);

        }
```